# Apply a function to each row of a numpy matrix w.r.t. its index

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy matrix **A** of shape [n,m] and an array **b** of length n. What I need is to take sum of **b**[i] least elements of the i'th row of **A**. 
So the code might look like this:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])

b = np.array([2,3,1])

sums = magic_function() #sums = [3, 15, 7]
```

I've considered np.apply_along_axis() function but it seems that your function can only depend on the row itself in this case.

Comment: Is A sorted by column?

Comment: In general case no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vectorized approach making use of [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create the mask of valid ones along each row and then perform `sum-reduction` -

```
mask = b[:,None] > np.arange(A.shape[1])
out = (A*mask).sum(1)
```

Alternatively, with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to get the `reduction` -

```
out = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A,mask)
```

We can also use `np.matmul/@ notation on Python 3.x` -

```
out = (A[:,None] @ mask[...,None]).squeeze()
```

Comment: I like how there's always an einsum solution in your answers.